# Gulp-sass fails to compile scss file

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm using Gulp to compile my sass into css. A simple task compiles the `style.scss` file in the `_/sass` directory and saves the output into the root of the project. `style.scss` is used merely to import other files in the `_/sass` directory.

When I run the default task from the command line (`$ gulp`) I get an error that the sass can't compile. It is included below in full. I have removed all content from the included files and run the task again. I still receive the same error (something I read online suggested this might test for an encoding issue. I don't fully understand encoding and how that might break things in my scenario).

I've also run from the command line `$ sass _/sass/style.scss style.css` which works perfectly with content in the included files. This suggests to me a problem with the gulp sass plugin itself.

The relevant snippets from gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile sass files
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./_/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});

// The default task (called when you run `gulp`)
gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.run('sass');

  // Watch files and run tasks if they change

  gulp.watch(['./_/sass/style.scss'], function() {
    gulp.run('sass');
  })
});
```

The full contents of style.scss:

```
/* RESET */
@import '_/sass/reset';
/* TYPOGRAPHY */
@import '_/sass/typography';
/* MOBILE */
@import '_/sass/mobile';
/* MAIN */
@import '_/sass/main';
```

The directory structure:

```
├── _
│   ├── inc
│   │   ├── stuff
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── otherstuff.js
│   └── sass
│       ├── main.scss
│       ├── mobile.scss
│       ├── print.scss
│       ├── reset.scss
│       ├── style.scss
│       └── typography.scss
├── gulpfile.js
└── style.css
```

Terminal spits out:

```
[gulp] Using file /Users/jeshuamaxey/project/dir/path/gulpfile.js
[gulp] Working directory changed to /Users/jeshuamaxey/project/dir/path/html5reset
[gulp] Running 'default'...
[gulp] Running 'sass'...
[gulp] Finished 'sass' in 3.18 ms
[gulp] Finished 'default' in 8.09 ms

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
source string:11: error: file to import not found or unreadable: 'reset'
```

Comment: Edited to include the full contents of style.scss

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Keep your imports as is, just pass the `includePaths` option in your gulp sass module as an argument:

```
gulp.src('./_/sass/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass({ includePaths : ['_/sass/'] }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
```

...should do it for you.

As per https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/1

Comment: Thanks. This solved the particular problem I was experiencing. Sadly my configuration is still not working as intended, but I'll persevere. I like the look of Gulp a lot

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to do start with same gulpfile.js folder

```
@import '_/sass/reset'
```

I think the Gulp reads the import and find the file from where gulpfile.js are located

Comment: Gulp-sass just updated with the new function that allow us to include path for @import https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-sass

Answer (score 0):

If you use Sublime text with Windows, you should add rules in Sunlime config. Just add `"atomic_save" : true` in Preferences>Settings-User

https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/wiki/Common-Issues-and-Their-Fixes#partials-sporadically-not-found