# gulp-sass: main scss file unable to find and load partials

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I am new to using gulp-sass and sass\scss structure in general, so bear with me!

I have a scss file in which I want to import some partials.

I have a styles folder in which lives my main scss file and a partials sub folder which contains a couple of files I wish to import in.

So at the top of my main.scss I have the typical:

```
@import 'partials/main_menu';
@import 'partials/main_usermenu';
```

Here are the relevant pieces of my gulp file:

```
var paths = {
  scss_files:'./src/assets/styles/**/*.scss'
}

gulp.task('compile_sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.scss_files, {base:'src'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'})
    .on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist))
});
```

When my gulp task runs, I get an error saying my main_menu partial was not found or unreadable and hence it fails to import.

Am I missing something in my task, e.g. is there some gulp-sass option I should be using or should it just work?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your sass file structure? Also try to remove the "base" parameter in the gulp.src function.

Comment: Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this? I'm running into a similar problem with the same error message while trying to import Twitter Bootstrap's sass file.

Answer (score 0):

After viewing this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957998/gulp-sass-fails-to-compile-scss-file) I was able to solve a similar problem I was having.

I believe if you add the 'includePath' option to the sass() function call that contains the parent path to your partials directory the error will go away.

i.e. something like 
`.pipe(sass({includePath: ['parent/PathTo/Partials'], outputStyle: 'compressed'})`